# R script has been wiped after reopening

Tags: r

I have an R script that appears to have been wiped of all contents when I reopened it in R Studio. The file size is 264 kb so it obviously contains something, but I cannot seem to retrieve anything.

Opening in a text editor shows no contents, and reopening it in R Studio with encoding doesn't appear to solve the issue. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: I actually had a very similar problem here. See if what I did in this question helps, though it sounds like by what you said about "encoding" you have already tried that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72057595/what-is-causing-my-r-script-text-to-disappear

Comment: Try a different editor.

Comment: @ user2554330 I tried opening it with Notepad and Notepad++, still no luck. @ 
Shawn Hemelstrand, yeah that seems to be a common workaround, unfortunately didn't work for me. Seems the file is corrupt and irretrievable.