# Why the content of R Markdown code on OneDrive disappeared?

Tags: r

I have been working on a project with multiple RMarkdown files since a few months ago. All files are in a RProj. on OneDrive.

For some reason, when I open the files now, only 2 of 10 files have the codes and others are totally blank! I see the files, but their content is empty.

I read about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72057595/what-is-causing-my-r-script-text-to-disappear) and [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/my-code-is-gone/126291).

As recommended, I checked to see if text-encoding is UTF-8 (the default value), and it was. I also tried opening the files in another text editor and Visual Studio Code. But I received the message that "an unexpected error happened" and I could not see their content. I closed and opened the RStudio, and uninstalled and installed it again. The issue still exists.

My system is a Mac, with RStudio version 2023.03.0+386 (2023.03.0+386) and R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31).

Can some one help with this?

Comment: Is the Rproj in a simple folder synced to OneDrive or in a github repository which was cloned into a OneDrive Folder?

Comment: Is the size of the files that appear to be empty zero?

Comment: The Rproj is in a simple folder on OneDrive and size of files that are appeared as empty is non-zero.

Comment: I found my codes on the online OneDrive's website.